# Rails 3.2.5 in `eval': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote a runner (saved in lib folder). When starting the runner with: rails runner lib/test.rb

```
 def aaa
     puts "aaa"
 end

 aaa
```

it dumps:
in `eval': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3) (ArgumentError)

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rails runner is intended to run code from your app codebase as in

(from the guide)

```
rails runner "Model.long_running_method" # parses the string and executes
                                         # the (hypothetical) method [long_running_method]
                                         # from (hypothetical) model [app/models/model.rb]
```

the error raises from the fact that in your call you don't provide a string to evaluate

anyway to make it work this way (with a function from lib) you should

- enclose your method in some class and
- make the class available requiring it someway during application boot

! pay attention: if you call `rails runner 'MyClass.my_method'` you're calling a class method which has to be defined properly

```
def self.my_method
  # your code
end
```

if you want to call an instance method you need to do `rails runner 'MyClass.new.my_method'`

All that said, rails runner boots all the rails app.

If that is not required, may I suggest to investigate whether a rake task could be suited for your needs ?